# python function handling giving error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, function, dataframe

Im trying to make my code kind of professional and function based my code is bellow:

```
def NOWT(nowt):#prints the number of words in the file
    nowt=wdata['sentences'].str.split().map(len).sum()
    print("Total number of the whole words: {}".format(nowt))
    return
def NOW(now): #prints the number of Tokanized words in the file
    now=data.str.split().map(len).sum()
    print("Total number of tokanized words: {}".format(now))
    return
def DIFF(diff):
    diff=NOWT(wdata)-NOW(data)
    print("The diff. is :{}".format(diff))
    return
NOW(now)
NOWT(wdata)
DIFF(data)
```

when I'm trying to get the sum of the output of 2 other functions is giving me this error :

```
 diff=NOWT(wdata)-NOW(data)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

any ideas what I did wrong ?

Comment: It is because you're returning nothing in the functions NOWT and NOW.

Comment: Where is NOS() function defined? Is this complete code ?

Comment: sorry my mistake fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening cause all the functions are returning None not any value. I presume you would like the value from the first declaration in each of the functions. The correct code would be:

```
def NOWT(nowt):#prints the number of words in the file
    nowt=wdata['sentences'].str.split().map(len).sum()
    print("Total number of the whole words: {}".format(nowt))
    return nowt
def NOW(now): #prints the number of Tokenized words in the file
    now=data.str.split().map(len).sum()
    print("Total number of tokanized words: {}".format(now))
    return now
def DIFF(diff):
    diff=NOWT(wdata)-NOW(data)
    print("The diff. is :{}".format(diff))
    return diff
NOW(data)
NOWT(wdata)
DIFF(data)
```

To prevent printing it twice:

```
def NOWT(wdata):#prints the number of words in the file
    nowt= wdata['sentences'].str.split().map(len).sum()
    print("Total number of the whole words: {}".format(nowt))
    return nowt

def NOW(data): #prints the number of Tokenized words in the file
    now= data.str.split().map(len).sum()
    print("Total number of tokenized words: {}".format(now))
    return now

def DIFF(now, nowt):
    diff=nowt-now
    print("The diff. is : {}".format(diff))
    return diff

now = NOW(data)
nowt = NOWT(wdata)
diff = DIFF(nowt, now)
```

Another option is removing the second last and third last line from the callbacks:

```
def NOWT(nowt):#prints the number of words in the file
    nowt=wdata['sentences'].str.split().map(len).sum()
    print("Total number of the whole words: {}".format(nowt))
    return nowt
def NOW(now): #prints the number of Tokenized words in the file
    now=data.str.split().map(len).sum()
    print("Total number of tokanized words: {}".format(now))
    return now
def DIFF(diff):
    diff=NOWT(wdata)-NOW(data)
    print("The diff. is :{}".format(diff))
    return diff
DIFF(data)
```

Comment: in this way its printing the  NOW and NOWT twice any ideas why ?```Total number of the whole words: 15
Total number of tokanized words: 15 Total number of the whole words: 15
Total number of tokanized words: 15
The diff. is :0```

Comment: This is happening as the function is called again which prints the values again. Best way would be to store the return values and pass them as parameters. Ill update my answer.

Comment: still prints it twice Total number of tokanized words: 15
Total number of the whole words: 15
Total number of the whole words: 15
Total number of tokanized words: 15
The diff. is :0

Comment: Which method are you trying?

Comment: Im trying the second method

Comment: Can you add some value for data and wdata so i can test it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205823/discussion-between-programming-freak-and-samay-gupta).

Comment: can you come to chat so I will be able to add code and files

Answer (score 1):

You can’t subtract `nonetype`. You have to convert your functions return to `int` or `float` to make it work.

Try it with

```
diff=int(NOWT(wdata))-int(NOW(data))
```